# Where is the sSwfPath path when using jquery-datatables-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, tabletools

I have set up Data Tables in my rails 4.1 project using the rweng/jquery-datatables-rails gem.

Everything works great except the Table Tools extension. The buttons show but they do not work.

I finally figured out that the reason the buttons don't work id because the path:

sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"

Does not exist.

The path is obviously within the gem file somewhere, but I've got no idea how to find it.

I finally got it to work by setting the path to:

sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go. Would rather use a local copy.

Many thanks

Comment: I tried copying the swf in local and try to give that path and it didn't work for me either. Did you get this fixed?